# How do read a Google Maps error code?

Tags: javascript

I am forcing a bad API key to generate errors while loading the [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) API via Ajax. The intention is to do a bit of an error handling if that scenario ever comes up.

Here is what I have:

```
var apiKey = 'xyz';
var protocol = window.location.protocol;

$.ajax({
    url: protocol + '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + apiKey + '&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete',
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(d){if error message is === '' do something},
    error: function(){alert('error')}
});
```

I get the error message in the console...

Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError which is accurate. The question is: How do I read this error message programmatically to do stuff? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Parsing as JSON doesn't work?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev -- what would I parse to JSON? :-)

Comment: What the API returns I suppose. IIRC google returns json.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev -- it actually returns a script not a json. So the error is a console error and thats why I am having a hard time getting the error message. The request itself returns a 200 so there is not problem with the request itself its after the sucess the script has problem because it fails to validate the api key. Which if fine. I wish I could get some some more meaningful error than just a console error